# How do I link an image in Godaddy server into my html email body

Tags: html, email

I am currently trying to set up an html email template for my ASP.net application. Emailing part is working but my image link inside the template does not. Following is the body of the email template. I am sure its an issue with Godaddy server where it does not allow the image to be shared publically.

```
    <body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <img src="www.mocking.com/Images/Public/welcome.jpg" width="100%" alt="">
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="text-center">
          <h1>Welcome to Mocking.com</h1>
          <br>
        </div>
          <i>Please click on "Confirm Activation"</i>

        <p > Some Text Some text Some Text  Some Text #@PARAM1 text Some Text  Some Text Some text Some Text  Some Text Some text Some Text  Some Text Some text Some Text  Some Text Some text Some Text  Some Text Some text Some Text  Some Text Some text Some Text  Some Text Some text Some Text  Some Text Some text Some Text  </p>

        <div class="cls_btn">Activate User</div>

        <div > Some Text Some text Some #@PARAM2 Some Text Some text Some Text  Some Text Some text Some Text  Some Text Some text Some Text  Some Text Some text Some Text  Some Text Some text Some Text  Some Text Some text Some Text  Some Text Some text Some Text  Some Text Some text Some Text  Some Text Some text Some Text <span class="cls_link">Mocking.com </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
      </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Could someone help me how to setup the images public so that email link works fine?

This is my image folder setup at Godaddy.

[image]

Thanks,
PG

File permission is set here but there is nothing specific. Everything has read.

[image]

Full folder structure
[image]

Comment: Make sure you check the file and folder permissions.

Comment: A quick fix would be if you are running out of time use https://imgbb.com/

Comment: How do I set the permission where ? Godaddy customer service is hopeless. I did the permission but there is no anything specific to say the images are public

Comment: Can you share the entire folder structure image? Is this shared server ?

Comment: I added the expanded folder tree.  I found a link to set permissions @ https://www.godaddy.com/help/set-directory-permissions-windows-6481 but I can not find them in File manager.

Comment: try this https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/12.5/customer-guide/websites-and-domains/website-content/setting-file-and-directory-access-permissions.70738/

Comment: None of the methods did work. I have a Windows Web hosting account. That should not be a problem right ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176201/discussion-between-pcg-and-shahil-m).